# How do I invite a friend to play Super Street Fighter IV?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv, street-fighter-iv

In regular (not Super) Street Fighter IV you could create player matches. You could make a player match friends-only, invite your friend, and play tons of matches.

In Super Street Fighter IV, there are no player matches anymore. I can invite my friends if I create a game in endless mode or team mode, but not in 1v1 mode. Every time I try to click invite friend, it is always grayed out. Even if we create a party the option to invite party to game is also grayed out.

How do I create a 1v1 match in SSFIV and invite someone from my friends list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Endless mode with the lobby set to just 2 people is the replacement for player matches. Set the other slot to private and you get a friend-only 1v1 mode.

Comment: So there's no way to do it outside of endless mode?